# Why does my code sometimes identify "?!" as symbols and sometimes not

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Python program that will encode a string. But first, I have to separate the symbols from the letters.
ends is a list of all the characters whereas kors is supposed to be a new list with the letters and the characters separated.

```
ends = ["s", "o", " ", "w", "h", "a", "t", "?", "!"] 
kors = [""]
letts = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

def char(x):
    if letts.find(x)== -1:
        return "symb"
    else:
        return "lett"
    
#note: the function char returns correctly
#now, we transfer the letters and symbols to kors
while len(ends)>0:
    print(char(ends[0]))
    #checking if kors is empty, to avoid errors with "kors[-1]"
    if len(kors)==0:
        kors.append(ends[0])
        ends=ends[1:]
        print(kors)
    #if the assigned character is a symb
    elif char(ends[0]) == "symb":
        #if the last character is a symb, combine both strings
        if char(kors[-1]) == "symb":
            kors[-1]=kors[-1]+ends[0]
            ends=ends[1:]
        #if not, append the assigned character
        else:    
            kors.append(ends[0])
            ends=ends[1:]
    #if the assigned character is a letter
    else:
        #if the last character is a symb, append the assigned character
        if char(kors[-1]) == "symb":
            kors.append(ends[0])
            ends=ends[1:]
        #if not, combine both strings
        else:
            kors[-1]=kors[-1]+ends[0]
            ends=ends[1:]
#prints final result
print(kors)
```

Based on this code, when I put in "so what?!", the " " and "?!" were identified as symbols but were not separated from "so what". Therefore, kors ended up as:

```
['so ', 'wh', 'at?!']
```

instead of

```
["so", " ", "what", "?!"]
```

(I'm using Python 3.9.0 by the way)

How can I get my desired outcome?

Edit: for some reason, I can't reproduce the ["so what?!"] from the original code, but my new result is still not the result I wanted. Please help.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your posted code does not produce the given output. As written, there is no handling of the `char(ends[0]) == "lett"` case.

Comment: @Prune, I have just edited the code. My apologies for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: @Adam Smith, the code has been edited. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making the mechanics of this much harder than necessary.

- There is already a string method to determine whether a string is entirely letters: `isalpha`.
- The basic process is to gather characters of the same classification: either letter or symbol.  You don't need to code those as separate cases: all the matters is whether the current character is of the same classification as the previous one.
- If they're the same, add the new character to the current "word".
- If not, put the current "word" into `kors` and start accumulating a new "Word".

Code:

```
ends = ["s", "o", " ", "w", "h", "a", "t", "?", "!"] 
kors = []

# Gather substrings of the same classification.
prev = ends[0]
str  = ends[0]

# Check the previous character against the current one.
for char in ends[1:]:
    if prev.isalpha() == char.isalpha():
        str += char
        print("adding", str)
    else:
        kors.append(str)
        print("filing", str, kors)
        str = char
prev = char

kors.append(str)
print(kors)
```

Output:

```
adding so
filing so ['so']
filing   ['so', ' ']
adding wh
adding wha
adding what
filing what ['so', ' ', 'what']
adding ?!
['so', ' ', 'what', '?!']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still not extremely confident with my Python skills, so this will help. Your help is greatly appreciated and I hope I can improve further from this.

Comment: by the way, I didn't know there was such a function. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I know the feeling.  That's why I still review basic tutorials once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
This might help you out.

```
ends = ["s", "o", " ", "w", "h", "a", "t", "?", "!"] 
kors = []
letts = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

def char(x):
    if letts.find(x) == -1:
        return "symb"
    else:
        return "lett"
    
#note: the function char returns correctly
#now, we transfer the letters and symbols to kors
while len(ends)>0:
    print(char(ends[0]))
    #checking if kors is empty, to avoid errors with "kors[-1]"
    if len(kors) == 0:
        kors.append(ends[0])
        ends=ends[1:]
    #if the assigned character is a symb
    elif char(ends[0]) == "symb":
        #if the last character is a symb, combine both strings
        if char(kors[-1][-1]) == "symb":
            kors[-1]=kors[-1]+ends[0]
            ends=ends[1:]
        #if not, append the assigned character
        else:
            #print(ends[0], '4444')
            kors.append(ends[0])
            ends=ends[1:]
    #if the assigned character is a letter
    else:
        #if the last character is a symb, append the assigned character
        if char(kors[-1][-1]) == "symb":
            kors.append(ends[0])
            ends=ends[1:]
        #if not, combine both strings
        else:
            kors[-1]=kors[-1]+ends[0]
            ends=ends[1:]

#prints final result
print(kors)
```

**Output:**

```
lett
lett
symb
lett
lett
lett
lett
symb
symb
['so', ' ', 'what', '?!']
```